# Zero-dimensionality implies $\pi$- regularness

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1. An element $a$ in $R$ is said $\pi$-regular if $a^n = a^nra^n$ for some $r \in R$ and a natural number $n$. A ring $R$ is called $\pi$-regular if  every element is $\pi$-regular.

> Is any zero dimensional ring a $\pi$-regular ring?

Note: Zero dimensional= every prime ideal is maximal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Results like this have definitely been known since the $80's$, when there was some interest in embeddability of rings in $0$-dimensional rings (like the work of Arapovic in the early 80's).  Robert Gilmer wrote and coauthored a number of papers about $0$-dimensional rings in the late 80's and early 90's.  A number of proofs of this fact might start with an element-wise observation like the following.

> **(M)** The following are equivalent for an element $a \in R$ and a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>   $(1)$ There exists $r \in R$ such that $a^n = a^{2n}r$
>   $(2)$ There exists $r \in R$ such that $a^n = a^{n+1}r$
>   $(3)$ There exists a (unique) idempotent $e \in R$ and an $r
>  \in R$ such that $[a(1-e)]^n = 0$ and $e(ra - 1) = 0$, and $a^nR = eR$ .
>   $(4)$ There exists a (unique) idempotent $e \in R$ such that $a^n R = eR$

**Proof**:

Given $(1)$, take $e = a^n r$ and $r' = ra^{n-1}$ and the check that $a[(1-e)]^n = 0$ and that $e(ra - 1) = 0$ with $r = r'$ is straightforward, which gives $(3)$

Given $(3)$, since $(1-e)$ is idempotent we have $a^n(1-e) = 0$.  Then substituting $e = era$ we have $a^n(1 - era) = 0$.  So $a^n = a^{n+1}er$ and $(2)$ holds.

Given $(2)$, take $r' = r^n$.  Indeed, we have $a^n = a^{n+1}r = ar a^n$, so iterating we get $a^n = a^n r^n a^n$.

Given $(3)$, note that the relation $a^n(1-e) = 0$ implies $e$ divides $a^n$, and the relation $e(ra-1) = 0$ implies that $e = e^n = er^na^n$ and hence $a^n$ divides $e$.  Thus $eR = a^nR$, and the idempotent $e$ is unique because $eR = fR$ always implies $e = f$ (indeed, if $es = f$ and $ft = e$ then $ef = e(es) = es = f$ and $ef = ft(f) = ft = e$ so $f = e$).

Given $(4)$, it's clear that $(1-e)$ annihilates $eR = a^nR$, so $[a^n(1-e)]^n = 0$.  Also there is an $r'$ such that $r'a^n = e$, and hence $r'a^ne = e$ and $e(r'a^n - 1) = 0$, so taking $r = r'a^{n-1}$ we are done.  Since the idempotents in $(3)$ and $(4)$ are the same by proof, uniqueness carries over from $(4)$ to $(3)$.  $\square$

As a bonus, condition $(3)$ makes transparent that

> In a reduced ring $R$, the equivalent properties of **(M)** are moreover equivalent to $a^2R = aR$.  Thus for reduced rings, being $\pi$-regular and Von Neumann Regular are the same thing.

We also have

> In a local ring $(R, \mathfrak{m})$, the equivalent properties of **(M)** are moreover equivalent to the statement that $a$ is either a unit or nilpotent.

This follows immediately from $(4)$ and the fact that in a local ring the only idempotents are $1$ and $0$.

> A reduced ring is $0$-dimensional iff it is Von Neumann Regular.

Standard, but a quick sketch is.... ($\implies$).  Consider $aR/a^2R$ for any $a$.  Using the facts that localization commutes with quotients and that $R_P$ is a field for any minimal prime of a reduced ring, and that being $0$ is a local property of modules, it's clear that $aR/a^2R$ is the zero module, hence $aR = a^2R$.  Conversely, if $R$ is a VNR, then **(M)** says $aR = eR$ for some idempotent $e$, and so $a$ is either a unit or $0$ in any localization.  Thus every localization is a field and $R$ is zero-dimensional.

> A ring is zero-dimensional if it is $\pi$-regular (i.e. every element satisfies property **(M)**.

We prove this by reducing to the reduced case, which was taken care of above.

Note that $R' = R/Rad(R)$ (where $Rad(R)$ is the nilradical of $R$) has the same Krull dimension as $R$, and that the homomorphic image of a $\pi$-regular ring is obviously $\pi$-regular.  That $R/Rad(R)$ being $\pi$-regular implies $R$ being $\pi$-regular follows because if $a^2R' = R'$ then by definition $(a-a^2r) \in Rad(R)$ for some $r \in R$.  Thus there exists an $n$ such that $(a - a^2r)^n = 0$, and binomial expansion immediately shows that $a^{n+1}$ divides $a^n$ in $R$.

Answer (score 3):

This is in some sense "obvious" from the basic algebro-geometric theory of reduced $0$-dimensional (i.e., von Neumann regular) rings.  In particular, suppose $R$ is a $0$-dimensional ring and let $N$ denote its nilradical.  Then $R/N$ is von Neumann regular, and so any principal ideal is generated by an idempotent.  In geometric terms, if $a\in R/N$ generates the same ideal as the idempotent $e$, then $e$ gives a partition of $\operatorname{Spec} R/N$ into two clopen sets such that $a$ is $0$ on one of them and a unit on the other.  (Explicitly, if $e=ab$ and $a=ea$, then $a$ is a unit with inverse $b$ on the clopen set obtained by inverting $e$, but is $0$ on its complement where $1-e$ is inverted.)

Now let's pull things back to $R$.  Given an element $a\in R$, its image in $R/N$ gives a partition of $\operatorname{Spec} R/N$ into clopen sets $U$ and $V$ such that $a$ is $0$ on $U$ and a unit on $V$.  But the natural map $\operatorname{Spec} R/N\to \operatorname{Spec} R$ is a homeomorphism, so we can consider $U$ and $V$ as subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ and the statements above will be true modulo nilpotent elements.  Specifically, $a$ will be nilpotent on $U$ and a unit on $V$ (since a unit plus a nilpotent is still a unit).  But now it is easy to prove $a$ is $\pi$-regular: if $n$ is large enough then $a^n$ is $0$ on $U$ and still a unit on $V$, and so we can take $r$ to be any element of $R$ which is the inverse of $a^n$ on $V$.

---

Alternatively, here's a more direct geometric proof that for any $a\in R$, there is a partition of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ into clopen sets $U$ and $V$ such that $a$ is nilpotent on $U$ and a unit on $V$.  Note that for any prime $P\subset R$, every element of $R_P$ is either a unit or nilpotent (since it has only one prime ideal, which thus is the nilradical).  Note moreover that if $a$ is nilpotent (or a unit) in $R_P$, there is an entire open neighborhood of $P$ on which $a$ is nilpotent (or a unit), since we can invert a single element of $R\setminus P$ to witness this.  So, if $U$ is the set of $P\in\operatorname{Spec} R$ such that $a$ is nilpotent in $R_P$ and $V$ is the set of $P\in\operatorname{Spec} R$ such that $a$ is a unit in $R_P$, then $U$ and $V$ are both open.  But since they are complements of each other, they are both clopen.

Now we just have to verify that $a$ is globally nilpotent on $U$ and globally a unit on $V$, rather than just locally.  For $V$, this is just the fact that a ring element that is not in any prime ideal is a unit (or more geometrically, since inverses are unique, we can patch together local inverses to $a$ on $V$ to get a global inverse).  For $U$, we use the fact that $U$ is covered by open sets on which $a$ is nilpotent (since as above, if $a$ is nilpotent in $R_P$ it is nilpotent on an open neighborhood of $P$).  But $U$ is closed in $\operatorname{Spec} R$ and thus quasicompact, so it is covered by finitely many open sets on which $a$ is nilpotent.  We can thus find $n$ such that $a^n=0$ on all of these finitely many open sets, so $a$ is nilpotent on $U$.

---

Finally, let me mention that the converse (every $\pi$-regular ring is $0$-dimensional) is true and comparatively trivial.  Indeed, suppose $R$ is $\pi$-regular and let $P\subset R$ be a prime ideal.  Replacing $R$ with $R/P$, we may assume in fact $R$ is a $\pi$-regular domain and we wish to show it is a field.  But in a domain, $a^n=a^nra^n$ implies either $a^n=0$ (and thus $a=0$) or $1=ra^n$.  So for any $a$, either $a=0$ or $a$ is a unit, which means $R$ is a field.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following results, so I think it is an answer for the question.

> [1, Corollary 11]: Every zero dimensional ring is clean.
>
> [2,  Corollary 2.8]: The following statements are equivalent for a commutative ring $R$:
>
> (a) $R$ is a clean ring with Krull dimension zero;
>
> (b) $R$ is a $\pi$-regular ring.

By combining above results we have: a commutative ring is zero dimensional if and only if it is $\pi$-regular!!!

[1] D. D. Anderson and V. P. Camillo, Commutative rings whose elements are a sum of
a unit and an idempotent, Comm. Algebra 30 (2002), 3327-3336.

[2] D. Lu, W. Yu, On prime spectrums of commutative rings, Comm. Algebra, 34, (2006), 2667-2672.